# Reference request and proof verification about using a generalized version of a theorem

Tags: reference-request, solution-verification, algebraic-number-theory

I'm not sure if what I'm writing is right or wrong, and I feel like I'm walking on water and I'm not feeling well at all. I construct a proof based on modeling and intuition from $L/\mathbb{Q}$, applied to $L/F$. In some sense, my question is: Is the Dedekind-Kummer factorization holds for any extension of number fields? Let $F$ be a number field, and let $L=F(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_L$. And let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime of $\mathcal{O}_F$ such that $\mathfrak{p} \nmid [\mathcal{O}_L: \mathcal{O}_F[\alpha]]$. Then the factorization of $\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_L$, can be obtained by the factorization of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ module $\mathfrak{p}$. Do we have this? If this is true, could you please show a written version of this theorem, in online notes or books or ...?

My original attempt is as follows. Let $F$ be a number field, and let $L=F(\sqrt[3]{u})$ for some $u \in \mathcal{O}_F$. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime of $\mathcal{O}_F$ such that $\mathfrak{p} \nmid 3u$. Then $\mathfrak{p}$ is unramified in $L=F(\sqrt[3]{u})$.

I made this proof by imitating my observations from the case when the base field is $\mathbb{Q}$. The minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{u}$ is $x^3-u$, which has a discriminant $3u^2$. Since $\mathfrak{p} \nmid 3u$, so we have $\mathfrak{p} \nmid 3u^2$, so $x^3-u$ is separable module $\mathfrak{p}$. Therefore $\mathfrak{p}$ is unramified in $\mathcal{O}_L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we have the general version of Kummer-Dedekind's factorisation theorem. You can have a look at Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory, p.47-48.