# showing an extension is unramifed by decomposition groups

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$. I can prove that $F(\sqrt{5})/F$ is an unramified extension in three ways, using any of these two questions [Reference request and proof verification about using a generalized version of a theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3976593/reference-request-and-proof-verification-about-using-a-generalized-version-of-a) , [Counter example relating the ramification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3978210/counter-example-relating-the-ramification) and also by Different ideal. I know that the two linked questions are almost the same, and they should be counted as one.

I want also to prove it by decomposition and inertia group. But I can not finish the idea. Assume $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5},{i})$ and $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$. Let $\mathfrak{P}\mid\mathfrak{p}\mid p$ be primes respectively in $K$, $F$ and $\mathbb{Q}$. Suppose on contrary that $e(\mathfrak{P}\mid\mathfrak{p})=2$. We have two cases $e(\mathfrak{p}\mid p)=2$ or $e(\mathfrak{p}\mid p)=1$.

First suppose that we have $e(\mathfrak{p}\mid p)=2$, then we have $e(\mathfrak{P}\mid p)=4$. By considering the multiplicativity of ramification index and the degree of extensions, this implies that $p$ ramifies in both of the $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})$. So $p$ divides both of $5$ and $-4$, which is obviously impossiblee.

Now suppose that we have $e(\mathfrak{p}\mid p)=1$, then $p$ is unramified in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$. So $p$ does not divides $-20$, so $p$ does not divides none of $5$ and $-4$. So $p$ is unramified in both of the $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})$. I can not go further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a prime $$\mathfrak{P} \subset O_{EF}$$ If $$e(\mathfrak{P}\cap O_F,F/\Bbb{Q})=1$$ then
$$e(\mathfrak{P},EF/E)=1$$
so that $$e(\mathfrak{P},EF/\Bbb{Q})=e(\mathfrak{P},EF/E)e(\mathfrak{P}\cap O_E,E/\Bbb{Q})=e(\mathfrak{P}\cap O_E,E/\Bbb{Q})$$

To show it from the Galois groups, for $E/\Bbb{Q},F/\Bbb{Q}$ both Galois and $E\cap F=\Bbb{Q}$ then $Gal(EF/\Bbb{Q})=Gal(E/\Bbb{Q})\times  Gal(F/\Bbb{Q})$ so you want to prove that $I(\mathfrak{P},EF/\Bbb{Q})$ is a subgroup of $I(\mathfrak{P}\cap O_E,E/\Bbb{Q})\times I(\mathfrak{P}\cap O_F,F/\Bbb{Q})$ which is more or less immediate as $g\times h$ sends $\mathfrak{P}$ to itself and acts trivially on the residue field implies that $h$ sends $\mathfrak{P}\cap O_F$ to itself and acts trivially on the residue field.

Comment: Is it possible to complete the proof without using https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3978210/counter-example-relating-the-ramification I can not touch the traces of decomposition or inertia groups in your proof. Where in the proof did you use decomposition or inertia groups? I should emphasize that your proof is very instructive and very useful for me.

Comment: For $E/Q,F/Q$ both Galois and $E\cap F=Q$ then $Gal(EF/Q)=Gal(E/Q)\times  Gal(F/Q)$ so you want to prove that $I(\mathfrak{P},EF/Q)$ is a subgroup of $I(\mathfrak{P},E/Q)\times I(\mathfrak{P},F/Q)$ which is more or less immediate